# error C3861: '_T': identifier not found , unable to pass in main function parameters as function parameters

Tags: c++, debugging, gmail

I am following this [guide](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vc.aspx?cat=2) on using C++ to send emails. I followed the instructions and it works perfectly fine

This is the sample code on how to send emails using the program , I have changed the email address and password for security purposes

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "easendmailobj.tlh"
using namespace EASendMailObjLib;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize( NULL );

    IMailPtr oSmtp = NULL;
    oSmtp.CreateInstance( "EASendMailObj.Mail");
    oSmtp->LicenseCode = _T("TryIt");

    // Set your gmail email address
    oSmtp->FromAddr = _T("randomemail1.lim@gmail.com");

    // Add recipient email address
    oSmtp->AddRecipientEx( _T("randomemail2s@hotmail.com"), 0 );

    // Set email subject
    oSmtp->Subject = _T("simple email from Visual C++ with gmail account");

    // Set email body
    oSmtp->BodyText = _T("this is a test email sent from Visual C++ project with Gmail");

    // Gmail SMTP server address
    oSmtp->ServerAddr = _T("smtp.gmail.com");

    // If you want to use direct SSL 465 port, 
    // Please add this line, otherwise TLS will be used.
    // oSmtp->ServerPort = 465;

    // detect SSL/TLS automatically
    oSmtp->SSL_init();

    // Gmail user authentication should use your 
    // Gmail email address as the user name. 
    // For example: your email is "gmailid@gmail.com", then the user should be "gmailid@gmail.com"
    oSmtp->UserName = _T("somerandomemail@gmail.com");
    oSmtp->Password = _T("somepassword");

    _tprintf(_T("Start to send email via gmail account ...\r\n" ));

    if( oSmtp->SendMail() == 0 )
    {
        _tprintf( _T("email was sent successfully!\r\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf( _T("failed to send email with the following error: %s\r\n"),
            (const TCHAR*)oSmtp->GetLastErrDescription());
    }

    if( oSmtp != NULL )
        oSmtp.Release();

    int x;
    cin>>x;

    return 0;
}
```

When i attempt to copy paste this code into my program and make it as a function which i can use , I get the following error

```
error C3861: '_T': identifier not found
```

This is what my functions looks like

```
void DriverClass::send_email(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize( NULL );

    IMailPtr oSmtp = NULL;
    oSmtp.CreateInstance( "EASendMailObj.Mail");
    oSmtp->LicenseCode = _T("TryIt");

    // Set your gmail email address
    oSmtp->FromAddr = _T("randomemail1.com");

    // Add recipient email address
    oSmtp->AddRecipientEx( _T("randomemail2@hotmail.com"), 0 );

    // Set email subject
    oSmtp->Subject = _T("simple email from Visual C++ with gmail account");

    // Set email body
    oSmtp->BodyText = _T("this is a test email sent from Visual C++ project with Gmail");

    // Gmail SMTP server address
    oSmtp->ServerAddr = _T("smtp.gmail.com");

    // If you want to use direct SSL 465 port, 
    // Please add this line, otherwise TLS will be used.
    // oSmtp->ServerPort = 465;

    // detect SSL/TLS automatically
    oSmtp->SSL_init();

    // Gmail user authentication should use your 
    // Gmail email address as the user name. 
    // For example: your email is "gmailid@gmail.com", then the user should be "gmailid@gmail.com"
    oSmtp->UserName = _T("randomemail1@gmail.com");
    oSmtp->Password = _T("randompassword");

    _tprintf(_T("Start to send email via gmail account ...\r\n" ));

    if( oSmtp->SendMail() == 0 )
    {
        _tprintf( _T("email was sent successfully!\r\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf( _T("failed to send email with the following error: %s\r\n"),
            (const TCHAR*)oSmtp->GetLastErrDescription());
    }

    if( oSmtp != NULL )
        oSmtp.Release();

    int x;
    cin>>x;


}
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that i cant pass in `int argc` and `_TCHAR*argc[]` as arguements , How do make it into a function which i can use and how do i solve it ???

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add:

```
#include <tchar.h>
```

as that is where the `_T` (and `_TCHAR`) macro is defined. See [Generic-Text Mappings in Tchar.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx).

Comment: Why does it work in my first example without the <tchar.h> header file ??

Comment: @Computernerd, it will be `#included`d in one of the other header files that are explicitly included. It is recommended to always explicitly include the header files required as compiler vendors will differ.